# Procedure or function has too many arguments specified C# DotNetNuke

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

I'm really at my wits end here. Basically because I'm not very familiar with DotNetNuke and the site I'm working on wasn't originally built by me therefore making it difficult to find files and directories I need to work on. I've searched high and low for a solution but I can't seem to get to the bottom of it and I'm sure this is probably a simple fix.

**Problem:** I have a form that the user fills out and then that data is inserted into a database table but I'm getting an error thrown at me.

**Error Thrown**: Procedure or function AddFranchiseFollowUp has too many arguments specified.

I've been at this for a few days and since I'm not very familiar with DotNetNuke I'm not sure if more  information is required to find a solution so I apologize in advance if that is the case. This source code was not written by me and this is how I found it, there is a working version of this form on the dev site and I've made sure the database for the live site is exactly the same as the dev. I just copied the module's files via FTP from the dev to the live site but I'm beginning to think I need to copy another file of some sort? I'm not sure what to do and I'm sorry if this is a dumb question but I need to figure this out one way or the other.

I've also double checked for typos in both the .ascx.cs and .ascx base file for any other irregularities but couldn't seem to pin point where my error is coming from. Hopefully I can get an answer and learn more about this too, thanks to all that read this and or provide a solution!

CodeFile FranchiseEnqDetails.ascx.cs Source:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using DotNetNuke;
using DotNetNuke.Common;
using DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities;
using DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules;
using DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions;
using DotNetNuke.Services.Localization;
using TemplateParser;
namespace YourCompany.Modules.FranchiseEnqDetails
{
partial class FranchiseEnqDetails : PortalModuleBase
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs FranchiseEnqDetails)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            hlFile1.Visible = false;
            hlFile2.Visible = false;
            lblSuccessMsg.Visible = false;
        }
    }
   protected void btnSubmit_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (INsertFPFranchiseUserDetails())
        {
            btnSubmit.Enabled = false;
            hlFile1.Visible = true;
            hlFile2.Visible = true;
            lblSuccessMsg.Visible = true;
        }
    }
internal bool INsertFPFranchiseUserDetails()
    {
        SqlConnection con = null;
        SqlCommand cmd = null;

        string ConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteSqlServer"].ToString();
        try
        {
con = new SqlConnection(ConnString);
            cmd = new SqlCommand();

            //cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FranchiseEnqName", txtFirstName.Text));
            //cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FranchiseEnqEmailId", txtEmailAddress.Text));
            //cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FranchiseEnqPhoneNo", txtPhoneNo.Text));
            //cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FranchiseEnqStreet", txtStreet.Text));
            //cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FranchiseEnqCity", txtCity.Text));
            //cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FranchiseEnqState", txtState.Text));
            //cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FranchiseEnqZip", txtZip.Text));

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FirstName", txtFirstName.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LastName", txtLastName.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EmailAddress", txtEmailAddress.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Address1", txtAddress1.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Address2", txtAddress2.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@City", txtCity.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fpState", txtState.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Zip", txtZip.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PhoneNo", txtPhoneNo.Text));

            con.Open();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "dbo.AddFranchiseFollowUp";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblError.Text = ex.Message;
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (con != null)
            {
                con.Close();
                con.Dispose();
                con = null;
            }

            if (cmd != null)
            {
                cmd.Dispose();

                cmd = null;
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The error message is descriptive enough. Open up the `AddFranchiseFollowUp` stored procedure in SQL Server Manager, and look for its parameters. Make sure you're specifying the same number of parameters and double check the names.

Answer (score 1):

If your Module is a compiled module, just making changes to the .CS file won't help, you will also need to recompile the module.

How do you tell if it is compiled? Check out the website's BIN folder, see if there is a DLL in there that matches the name of the module.

Comment: Also, if it is a compiled module, it doesn't necessarily have to be. You may be able to just remove the DLL and put the .cs file in the App_Code directory and that would cause the changes to be JIT compiled.